# Wifi noise interference in speakers

Tags: wireless-networking, audio, speakers

Is there a way to fix the noise interference I get from the wifi in my speakers ?

I tried to change channels, change the transmission from long to short and vice versa, ferrite cores around the speakers' cables. None helped.

So far the only solution I found is to decrease the transmission power, but then I don't have wifi in other rooms.

I found in ebay copper sleeving, do you think that can help if I'll put it on the cables ?

My audio system is 2.1. I can't really move the speakers or sub anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Look for "shielded speaker" or "Magnetically Shielded
 speaker" at your favourite online store.

You can find shielded speakers from 15$ up to 7000$.

Most computer speakers are magnetically shielded.

Comment: Yeah I'd rather not buy new speakers because these are pretty good and were not cheap back when I bought them.

Comment: Well, you can try to shield them yourself, by wrapping them in aluminium paper...